# Monotouch Installation to be used by a different user

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Ok. My admin installed monotouch under the admin account. When I log into that same machine I get an error saying something to the affect of **Monotouch has not been activated**.

I notice that under the admin\library folder there is a Monotouch folder with a license file in it. Under my Library folder I do not have a Monotouch folder with a license file.

Could this be the problem? Can I just copy the Monotouch folder to my library?

Bigger question - How do I install Monotouch to be used by different users on the same machine?

Comment: Afaik, MonoTouch is a per user, not a per machine license. In other words, they probably require you to activate a separate license per user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could this be the problem?

Yes. MonoTouch will be looking for its license file.

> Can I just copy the Monotouch folder to my library?

It should work (and there's no real harm in trying).

OTOH the easiest/safest solution would be to **re-install** MonoTouch from your (the final) user account. That will ensure the license file is created at the *right* location and with the *right* permissions.

In general all MonoTouch updates will be driven by MonoDevelop (based on the channel, **stable**, **beta** or **alpha**, that you subscribe) and this is executed under the (final) user account.